# launch script from http slows down website

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, http, ssh

to do photo remove background, I usually run a script via ssh.
Now, I would like to do it by external people who could launch this script via an administration interface.
The problem is that when we launch it via the interface, it slows down the site enormously during the execution time of the script.

I use this ajax to launch the script as follows (under php codeigniter):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-bg', function () {
    var file_id = $(this).attr('data-file-id');
    var data = {
        "file_id": file_id
    };
    data[csfr_token_name] = $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "file_controller/remove_bg",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get around this problem knowing that I can't give ssh access to these people
and i can't use cronjob because the pictures have to be checked manually

Comment: To avoid slowing down the website, it is recommended to use the `async` or `defer` attribute when including the script in the HTML file.

Comment: Or take a look at incron. A file-system change listener and write a short file that wil be picked up .  Or write the info to a db-table and let a cronjob take care of it.

Comment: ok with @Siebe Jongebloed solution (write info in db table and cron)

Answer (score 0):

**Your script has several problems.**

1. Let's assume that the script runs for 2 minutes, and during this time, the user has problems with the network. So you will not be able to show the result of your script on the backend because the ajax connection will be aborted.
2. The problem with your script is that it will interfere with the user's surfing. For example, suppose that the process lasts 2 minutes and the user does something during this time, and then the page will suddenly reload because you set the page to reload in the script after receiving a response from the server.

**In modern web applications, such problems are solved as follows**

1. The user started the process
2. You show the user a message that the process is started
3. You sent a request to the backend via ajax
4. On the backend, you start a background process and return the unique ID of this process.
5. The frontend saves this unique process ID
6. Every 10 seconds, you run a request to the backend to check if the process has finished its work
7. If the Frontent received a positive response that the work is over, then you can download a new picture from the server and show it to the user.

**How to organize it in your case?**
Here is the path that came to my mind. You are sending a request via ajax․ The backend starts the process. This can be done in the following way

```
exec("./your_process --failenewname=newname1.png > /dev/null &");
```

This command will start a background process on the backend. Your process should take a `failenewname` parameter and rename the image to this new name at the end of the job. After the background process is launched, you return to the frontend the path in which the new file will be located. Forontend gets the path and checks every 10 seconds if the file exists. When the background process on the backend finishes, this file will be created, and you can download it.